# Limiting links to appropriate text

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to make a navigation menu as well as a footer. It's going quite well, but they both contain links. And I am having trouble limiting the "link click area" to a small square just around the text. I can point my cursor several px next to a name in the menu and still hit a link. How would you fix this or rather: How would you limit a link, with a hover function, to the appropriate text?

Doing this in HTML and CSS!

```css
footer { 
  font-family: Moon Flower Bold; 
  font-size: 40px; 
  color: black; 
  background: rgba(0,138,99,0.4); 
  list-style-type: none; 
  Padding-bottom: 45px; 
} 

footer ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
} 

footer ul li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left; 
  width: 200px; 
} 

footer a:visited, 
a:link { 
  color: black; 
  text-decoration: none; 
} 

footer a:hover { 
  background-color: grey; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

```html
<footer> 
  <ul>
    <li>&copy; Gruppe 3</li>
    <li><a href="kontaktos.html">Kontakt Os</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: What language is this in?  HTML?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying! HTML and CSS for styling (:

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Yes! It's kind of a mess, I've only just started studying this stuff:

Comment: Try to narrow down your code only to what is relevant.  Your goal is to post a [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Well thought out and worded questions tend to get answered quickly on this site.

Comment: HTML:
<footer>
           <ul>
               <li>&copy; Gruppe 3</li>   
               <li><a href="kontaktos.html">Kontakt Os</a></li>
               <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>

                    
           </ul>
           
       </footer>

My footer, that's the one that looks really bad when you hover.

and my css:

Comment: footer {
    font-family: Moon Flower Bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
    background: rgba(0,138,99,0.4);
    list-style-type: none;
    Padding-bottom: 45px;
}

footer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
   
}

footer a:visited, a:link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;    
}

footer a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: Edit your question and add the code...Comments are too hard to read...

Comment: i don't know how to post the code. It says that it is not correct formatted. thanx for your patience though. I'll get back here later when I know more I guess

Comment: @ThomasBang I have added your code to the question for you.  A screenshot of the gap you're seeing would be helpful, though. It could be a variety of things, including the `Moon Flower Bold` font family which isn't rendered in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the clickable space by giving appropriate padding (In your case, 0) to the link tag, eg.

**HTML:**

```
<a class='links' href='http//...'>link1</a>
<a class='links' href='http//...'>link2</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.links{
    padding: 0;
}
```

This will result in making just the link text clickable.